# drupal 7 panels landing page, how to remove default theme elements

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-panels

I'm drupal beginner, and can't solve problem with landing page. I create landing page with panels, set custom css code to it but it doesn't look how I want. I see default elements from my theme (header, nav-menu, etc.) on it. I want that layout fill all my page, how can I achieve it?

[I have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTkGc.jpg)

[I want do like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQYjg.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please provide what you have tried and where you have failed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, I found solution for this problem. I use bootstrap 3 sub theme, and there is file who provide page template, it calls node.tpl.php. I just remove string `<div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">` and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

go to page.tpl.php file, remove the lines that render the header, the logo and the title. They would usually be in an if statement and the varibles are $logo, $site_name, $main_menu, $title.